# Pantheios for Android with NDK

Tags: windows, build, android-ndk, makefile, pantheios

How do I build Pantheios with the Android NDK for use with my JNI code on Windows?
I've written a custom back-end that uses the [Android Logging API](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#logging), but I don't know how to get the library itself to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the way to compile external libraries for Android is through [standalone toolchain](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html). If Pantheios is based on Cmake, there is a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake).

Comment: I couldn't get the standalone toolchain scripts to work on Windows. Unfortunately, Pantheios doesn't use CMake (yet?)

Comment: You need cygwin, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/6C55SW74_KA. I believe that cygwin is supported for Pantheios.